# How can I disable wake by mouse?

Tags: windows-10

How can I disable wake by mouse?

[image: powercfg]

[image: device manager mouse]

unchecking device manager did not solve problem

Comment: I can't upload image because less reputation Sorry

Comment: in cmd's korean is HID keyboard device

Comment: the second picture is HID standard mouse property

Comment: `powercfg /devicedisablewake /?`.

Comment: there is no mouse device

Comment: only `NVIDIA USB Type-C Port Policy Controller` and
`Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller` and
`HID keyboard device`

Comment: How to add a good inline image that improves the question:  Copy and paste in the body. Windows has an inbuilt hotkey (Win + Shift + S) which executes Snipping Tool. Any screen captured will be copied to the clipboard.

Comment: I can't upload image because less reputation Sorry

Comment: Can you translate the complex characters into English, or if not post them as text we can copy and paste into Google's translate.

Comment: I write in question but now disappear.
cmd is  HID keyboard device and
Second picture is HID standard mouse property
that's all
if I input korean character then Commnets cannot contain that content error occur

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 64-bit

How to disable wake by mouse: Device Manager - Mice and other pointing devices - "your mouse" right click - Properties - Power Management - uncheck "Allow this device to wake the computer"

If that fails disable wake by mouse in the BIOS.

[image: device manager mouse]

Comment: I did it already

It's not work

https://imgur.com/aPBH7iW

Comment: If that fails disable wake by mouse in the BIOS. Add to your question that unchecking device manager did not solve problem.

Comment: I tried but It's not work

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot, there are two HID Mouse devices, did you try to disable wakeup for both of them using the method suggested by @somebadhat ?

[image: scr1]

Even in below screenshot there are 3 HID devices, my guess is one being KB and other two with (001) and (002) are two mouses.

[image: scr2]

Comment: the other mouse dirver has not power manager
https://imgur.com/iXk4GBD
it doesn't work